# Python delete line and write over it

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have proplem here with my code

i am using for loop to save results in txt file

every time i use it it's saving the last line and delete the old line

here is code:

```
                 for i in domains:
                    requests.get(i)
                        if req.status_code == 200:
                            print('[+]:', i + '/')
                            file = open(save,'w')
                            file.write(domain)
                            file.close()
```

so after run the code it's save the last domain or last results and delete the old results

so i want solution 
thanks.

Comment: "every time i use it it's saving the last line and delete the old line."  What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Either open the file for appending, or open and close it outside the loop.

Comment: Going to untag `requests` here. This is not an issue related to the requests package.

Comment: There is **no variable** named `domain` so how can the file write it?

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in append mode:

```
open(filename,'a')
```

Your code should be:

```
for i in domains:
    requests.get(i)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        print('[+]:', i + '/')
        file = open(save,'a')
        file.write(i)
        file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try open it with `a` instead of `w`, so:

```
file = open(save, 'a')
```

it should appends to the file instead of writing to it

Answer (score 0):

You sould use 'a' instead of 'w' in "file = open(save,'w')"

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is arising because you are opening the file for writing on every iteration of the loop.  Because you are opening the file with mode `'w'`, the file is being overwritten every time.  (See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).)

It would be better to open the file once only, outside the loop.

For example:

```
                 file = open(save, 'w')
                 for i in domains:
                     # do some stuff...
                     file.write(some_data)
                 file.close()
```

You can also use `with` in conjuction with the `open` function:

```
                 with open(save, 'w') as file:
                     for i in domains:
                         # do some stuff...
                         file.write(some_data)
```

In this case, there is no need for an explicit call to `file.close()`.  This will be done automatically when the loop ends, or even if something happens inside the `with` block like an exception being raised (i.e. error occurring) or a `return` from the function (if applicable).

Be aware that because of output buffering, data written to the file during one iteration might not actually get written to the file until some later iteration or after the file is closed.  If this would be a problem, then you can insert a `flush` call to force a low-level write so that other processes can see the data:

```
                 with open(save, 'w') as file:
                     for i in domains:
                         # do some stuff...
                         file.write(some_data)
                         file.flush()
```

If there is some reason why you need to open the file inside the loop, then you could open it in append mode using `'a'`, and the data will be written after the end of the existing file.  (Again, see the documentation linked earlier.)  For example:

```
                 for i in domains:
                     # do some stuff...
                     file = open(save, 'a')
                     file.write(some_data)
                     file.close()
```

or again, better like this:

```
                 for i in domains:
                     with open(save, 'a') as file:
                         # do some stuff...
                         file.write(some_data)
```

Be aware that if the output file already exists before the program is started, then the contents of the existing file will remain because you are always opening it in append mode.  Depending on your application, this might or might not be desirable.